# How to access flatList methods such as scrollToIndex from a custom made flatlist component?

Tags: react-native

I created a custom `List` component from the react-native flatList component. Now I want to use the `scrollToIndex` method of the flatlist component using ref so that I can scroll to top of the list by pressing a custom button. But the scrollToIndex method seems to be not available when I create a custom component. How to make this work?

Comment: Add your code..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it down through props

Your custom component "list" file:

```
const List = (props) => {
  return (
    <Flatlist
      ref={(ref) => { this.listRef = ref; }}
      initialScrollIndex={this.props.initialScrollIndex}
    />
  );
};
```

In use:

```
scrollToIndex = () => {
this.listRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: whateverIndex});
}

<List
  initialScrollIndex={whateverIndex}
/>
```

Comment: Not sure if this works as my list component is a HOC and the actual flatlist is two levels down